# VBA Excel add hyperlink toward word bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I need to create a hyperlink from VBA which would be placed in an Excel cell and pointing toward a Word Bookmark.

I know how to generate the hyperlink but when clicked, it doesn't bring me to the bookmark but to text similar to the bookmark's name. Please note that I've also tried to record a macro making my hyperlink but unfortunately it doesn't see any bookmark (might be a bug ?)
the hyperlink created manually works.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sheets("DevisTest").Range("G10")
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a1"), _
Address:="C:\Users\somepath\file.docx", _
SubAddress:="#thebookmark", _
ScreenTip:="description of what clicking will do", _
TextToDisplay:="Text displayed by the link"
```

Comment: You simply have to remove the hash from the SubAddress

Answer (score 0):

[Ike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16578424/ike)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909987/vba-excel-add-hyperlink-toward-word-bookmark/72993787#comment128782507_72909987):

> You simply have to remove the hash from the SubAddress

was right. I already tried it and had no success because there was a typography error in the bookmark name.